# doctrine 2 order not work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following simple query:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('o')
    ->from('LibraryBundle:Publication', 'o')
    ;

    $qb
        ->join('o.translations', 't');

$qb
    ->orderBy('o.published_at', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults($count);
```

Without join all works fine, but with join order not work and I got first records, instead of last.
Relationship in Publication:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="PublicationTranslation",
 *     mappedBy="translatable",
 *     cascade={"persist"}
 * )
 */
private $translations;
```

What I doing wrong?

**UPD**: This DQL generate following SQL-query, but if I try this in phpMyAdmin order also wrong:

```
SELECT
    p0_.id AS id0,
    /* a number of fields */
    p1_.translatable_id AS translatable_id20
FROM publications p0_
INNER JOIN publication_translation p1_ ON p0_.id = p1_.translatable_id
ORDER BY p0_.published_at DESC LIMIT 3
```

**UPD2**: I solved my problem with this code, but I still don't understand why sorting by `published_at` doesn't work:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
     ->from('ItopLibraryBundle:Publication', 'o')
;

$qb
     ->select('o, t')
     ->join('o.translations', 't');

$qb
     ->orderBy('o.id', 'DESC')
     ->groupBy('o.id')
     ->setMaxResults($count);
```

Comment: What SQL queries do these DQL queries turn into?

Comment: What do you mean by order is wrong? Limiting an ordered query may give weird results...